# How do I disable suburbs in GeoLite2

Tags: php, geoip, maxmind

I am using GeoLite2-City.mmdb in my website. Its all working as required but the only problem is that it sometimes return suburb name instead of city name. Is there a way to always get the city name?

```
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;
$db = new Reader('/GeoLite2.mmdb');
$test = $db->city('CONFIG_IP_ADDRESSS');
echo $test ['city']['names']['en'];
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share with us your code so that we know where to start?

Comment: @YongQuan edited

Comment: What do you mean by "city name"? In the US, at least, suburbs are cities in their own right. Are you looking for the metropolitan area that the IP belongs to? MaxMind does not provide this.